# Python datetime to Matlab datenum

Tags: python, matlab, datetime

How do you convert a Python `datetime` to a Matlab `datetnum`?

Comment: Do you actually mean convert an object in one language to an object in another? If so, what interface are you using (PyMat?) Or do you mean how do you print out a datetime object in a particular format?

Comment: @DavidRobinson - nope, I mean to `datenum`'s textual representation which Matlab knows how to read. stuff like `732399.65465` where on the left is the gregorian day since 1/1/1 (or 1/1/0?!) and on the right is the fraction of a day

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To serialize datetime as a string, strftime can be used on the Python side:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.now()
print (d.strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

According to [MatLab docs](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html) datenum knows how to parse it.

Answer (score 9):

Based on bavaza's answer - now including microseconds:

```
def datetime2matlabdn(dt):
   mdn = dt + timedelta(days = 366)
   frac_seconds = (dt-datetime.datetime(dt.year,dt.month,dt.day,0,0,0)).seconds / (24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0)
   frac_microseconds = dt.microsecond / (24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0 * 1000000.0)
   return mdn.toordinal() + frac_seconds + frac_microseconds
```

Answer (score 6):

Reversing what was done [here](http://sociograph.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-avoid-gotcha-when-converting.html), I got:

```
def datetime2matlabdn(dt):
   ord = dt.toordinal()
   mdn = dt + timedelta(days = 366)
   frac = (dt-datetime(dt.year,dt.month,dt.day,0,0,0)).seconds / (24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0)
   return mdn.toordinal() + frac
```

Should work with `timedelta.microseconds` too.

In IDLE:

> *n = datetime.now()*
>
> *datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 13, 6, 56, 2, 619000)*
>
> *datetime2matlabdn(n)*
>
> *734912.28891203704*

In Matlab:

> *>> datestr(734912.28891203704)*
>
> *ans =
> 13-Feb-2012 06:56:02*

Comment: +1 slightly off-topic, but I had to do a similar conversion between MATLAB `datenum` and C# `System.DateTime` in an old answer of mine. Beside the different units used internally, the reference point in time was also off by 366 days: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7558811/97160

Comment: actually `datestr(734912.28891203704, 'mmmm dd, yyyy HH:MM:SS.FFF AM')` yields `February 13, 2012  6:56:02.000 AM` so it does not retain the milliseconds\microseconds information