# Can't transform matlab datenum format into python datetime with enough precision

Tags: python, matlab, datetime, time

I've got .mat file with datenum values (i.e. 735724.3229166666, 735725.6756944444 and etc.).

My goal is transform it into datetime format without losing precision, in other words it should work as precise as it would've worked with matlab.

I am perfectly aware of those answers:
[Converting Matlab's datenum format to Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965740/converting-matlabs-datenum-format-to-python)

But none of them work as precise, because python rounds everything up after decimal in almost every numerical operation.

For example, those functions I wrote are based on the answers in the link above:

```py
def datenum_to_datetime1(datenum):

    days = datenum % 1
    return datetime.fromordinal(int(datenum)) \
           + timedelta(days=days) \
           - timedelta(days=366)

def datenum_to_datetime2(datenum):

    days = np.float_(datenum) % 1
    return datetime.fromordinal(int(datenum)) \
           + timedelta(days=days) \
           - timedelta(days=366)

def datenum_to_datetime3(datenum):

    return pd.to_datetime(datenum-719529, unit='D')

def datenum_to_datetime4(datenum):

    origin = np.datetime64('0000-01-01', 'D') - np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
    date = datenum * np.timedelta64(1, 'D') + origin
    return date
```

If I try them on  735724.3229166666 , I get:

- 2014-05-05 07:44:59.999997
- 2014-05-05 07:44:59.999997
- 2014-05-05 07:45:00.000028800
- 2014-05-05

Third option is the most precise but with matlab it's still differs. Can someone help?

Comment: Why do you consider the third option to be the best? I assume your input is `2014-05-05 07:45:00`? If so it has an error of 2.8e-5 which is higher than the 3e-6 of the first two results.

Comment: @Daniel, I need minutes to be precise, :59 and :00 is a difference in my case

Comment: So you are not interested in anything smaller then seconds? If so round your time to the nearest second.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your input date was `2014-05-05 07:45:00`. Let's take a look at the precision in which MATLAB stores the date. It uses a 64bit floating point. At the values you have, the precision in seconds is `eps(735724)*24*60*60` or `1.0058e-05`. As long as you see errors within (half of) this number, they are already present in your input data and not caused by your conversion. If you need a higher resolution, you need input data with a higher accuracy.