# How to read Matlab datenum from CSV into Pandas as time-zone aware datetime?

Tags: pandas, matlab, datetime, timezone, read.csv

I have a Matlab datenum column in CSV file, e.g. 734622.540972.  This is for timezone of 'America/Vancouver'. This serialized date corresponds to Apr 29, 2011 12:58:59.981. I want to be able to read this in pandas in an efficient manner.  I have tried the following code but get Pandas warnings.  Can someone explain why the warning is there and how to modify this code so that it is compliant with future version of Pandas:

```
import datetime as dt
import pytz as tz
import pandas as pd

# this is a function to convert matlab_datenum to tz-aware Python datetime. It works correctly.


def convert_matlab_date(matlab_datenum):
    python_datetime = dt.datetime.fromordinal(int(
        matlab_datenum)) + dt.timedelta(days=matlab_datenum % 1) - dt.timedelta(days=366)

    some_tz = tz.timezone('America/Vancouver')
    new_dt = some_tz.localize(python_datetime)

    return new_dt


full_fname = "some_file_with_matlab_dates.csv"
col_names = ("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4",
             "col5")

some_df = pd.read_csv(full_fname,  header=None, names=col_names,
                      date_parser=convert_matlab_date)
```

---

This gives a pandas FutureWarning about using pd.to_datetime .  Output below:

```
c:\pd_matlab_conversion.py:29: FutureWarning: 
        Use pd.to_datetime instead.

  some_df = pd.read_csv(full_fname,  header=None, names=col_names,

some_df
Out[89]: 
                                    col1    col2    col3    col4       col5
2011-04-29 06:29:59.971196-07:00  346.86  346.67  347.40  346.74   163300.0
2011-04-29 06:31:00.019201-07:00  346.71  346.71  347.01  346.81    48500.0
2011-04-29 06:31:59.980805-07:00  346.81  346.80  347.12  347.09    55600.0
2011-04-29 06:33:00.028800-07:00  347.09  347.07  347.45  347.32    42300.0
2011-04-29 06:33:59.990404-07:00  347.29  347.27  347.90  347.80   104400.0
```

CSV Snippet below:

```
734622.270833,346.860000,346.670000,347.400000,346.740000,163300.000000
734622.271528,346.710000,346.710000,347.010000,346.810000,48500.000000
734622.272222,346.810000,346.800000,347.120000,347.090000,55600.000000
734622.272917,347.090000,347.070000,347.450000,347.320000,42300.000000
734622.273611,347.290000,347.270000,347.900000,347.800000,104400.000000
734622.274306,347.770000,347.750000,347.900000,347.900000,51900.000000
734622.275000,347.860000,347.830000,348.420000,348.220000,99100.000000
734622.275694,348.280000,348.170000,348.630000,348.530000,82600.000000
734622.276389,348.560000,348.550000,348.890000,348.880000,74700.000000
734622.277083,348.850000,348.820000,349.330000,349.290000,101500.000000
734622.277778,349.290000,349.290000,349.900000,349.880000,134600.000000
734622.278472,349.850000,349.580000,349.930000,349.740000,109500.000000
734622.279167,349.860000,349.610000,350.000000,349.730000,119100.000000
```

Comment: like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49135037/10197418

Comment: i already used that information to write the function  convert_matlab_date() which correctly does the conversion of datenum to Python tz-aware datetime.  My issue is that pandas is issuing a warning to use pd.datetime.  I want to know what causes the warning.

Comment: I wrote a wrap-up of how you can apply the answer I linked to your case. In principle, the warning points you to using pandas methods, instead of those from vanilla Python. In general, that's the recommended way (if working with pandas), pandas built-ins tend to be more efficient and make for cleaner code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matlab's [datenum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html#description) is

> A serial date number represents the whole and fractional number of days from a fixed, preset date (January 0, 0000) in the proleptic ISO calendar.

[pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) can convert fractional days to datetime, however year 0000 would be out of range. So you need to normalize that epoch to a reasonable one first. As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49135037/10197418), you can do that like

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"datenum": [734622.270833,734622.271528,734622.272222,734622.272917,
                               734622.273611,734622.274306,734622.275000,734622.275694,
                               734622.276389,734622.277083,734622.277778,734622.278472,
                               734622.279167]})

epoch = 719529 # full days between 0000-01-00 and 1970-01-01

# normalize to 1970-01-01 as epoch, convert to datetime and set time zone
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datenum"]-epoch, unit="d").dt.tz_localize("America/Vancouver")

df["datetime"]

0    2011-04-29 06:29:59.971196416-07:00
1    2011-04-29 06:31:00.019201024-07:00
2    2011-04-29 06:31:59.980805120-07:00
3    2011-04-29 06:33:00.028799488-07:00
4    2011-04-29 06:33:59.990403584-07:00
5    2011-04-29 06:35:00.038397952-07:00
6    2011-04-29 06:36:00.000002048-07:00
7    2011-04-29 06:36:59.961595904-07:00
8    2011-04-29 06:38:00.009600512-07:00
9    2011-04-29 06:38:59.971204352-07:00
10   2011-04-29 06:40:00.019198976-07:00
11   2011-04-29 06:40:59.980803072-07:00
12   2011-04-29 06:42:00.028797440-07:00
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns, America/Vancouver]
```

Comment: thanks! is there a quick way to round off the datetime values to nearest second? e.g. first value 2011-04-29 06:29:59.971196416-07:00 should round off to 2011-04-29 06:30:00.0-07:00

Comment: @BuddyLi use [.dt.round("s")](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html)