# Can a Matlab or IDL user cope with a Python datetime object?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, hdf5

I have unfortunately no way to check this, because I have no IDL or Matlab licenses, that's why I'm asking here.

The scenario is that I am saving HDF5 files with pandas and one of the columns is a Python datetime object. There are good HDF5 reading libraries for IDL and Matlab (so I have heard at least), but would a IDL/Matlab user be able to do anything useful with the datetime object found in the HDF5 file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776414/python-datetime-to-matlab-datenum

Comment: I have seen that, but the answers only suggest to serialize to a string on the Python side, which is not what I want, if I can avoid it. Storing the datetime object would be much more efficient for me.

Comment: @TomRon The referenced question doesn't answer this, they just say "make it a string" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [28]: df = DataFrame({ 'A' : np.random.rand(5), 
                          'B' : range(5), 
                          'C' : date_range('20130101',periods=5,freq='T')})

In [29]: df
Out[29]: 
          A  B                   C
0  0.067509  0 2013-01-01 00:00:00
1  0.872840  1 2013-01-01 00:01:00
2  0.379634  2 2013-01-01 00:02:00
3  0.552827  3 2013-01-01 00:03:00
4  0.996150  4 2013-01-01 00:04:00

[5 rows x 3 columns]

In [30]: df.dtypes
Out[30]: 
A           float64
B             int64
C    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Write out a `Table` format.

```
In [32]: df.to_hdf('test.h5','df',mode='w',format='table')
```

Show the internal structure of the file

```
In [33]: !ptdump -avd test.h5
/ (RootGroup) ''
  /._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 4 attributes:


n [32]: df.to_hdf('test.h5','df',mode='w',format='table')

In [33]: !ptdump -avd test.h5
/ (RootGroup) ''
  /._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 4 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    PYTABLES_FORMAT_VERSION := '2.1',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0']
/df (Group) ''
  /df._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 14 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0',
    data_columns := [],
    encoding := None,
    index_cols := [(0, 'index')],
    info := {1: {'type': 'Index', 'names': [None]}, 'index': {}},
    levels := 1,
    nan_rep := 'nan',
    non_index_axes := [(1, ['A', 'B', 'C'])],
    pandas_type := 'frame_table',
    pandas_version := '0.10.1',
    table_type := 'appendable_frame',
    values_cols := ['values_block_0', 'values_block_1', 'values_block_2']]
/df/table (Table(5,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "values_block_0": Float64Col(shape=(1,), dflt=0.0, pos=1),
  "values_block_1": Int64Col(shape=(1,), dflt=0, pos=2),
  "values_block_2": Int64Col(shape=(1,), dflt=0, pos=3)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (2048,)
  autoindex := True
  colindexes := {
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False}
  /df/table._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 19 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'TABLE',
    FIELD_0_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_0_NAME := 'index',
    FIELD_1_FILL := 0.0,
    FIELD_1_NAME := 'values_block_0',
    FIELD_2_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_2_NAME := 'values_block_1',
    FIELD_3_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_3_NAME := 'values_block_2',
    NROWS := 5,
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '2.7',
    index_kind := 'integer',
    values_block_0_dtype := 'float64',
    values_block_0_kind := ['A'],
    values_block_1_dtype := 'int64',
    values_block_1_kind := ['B'],
    values_block_2_dtype := 'datetime64',
    values_block_2_kind := ['C']]
  Data dump:
[0] (0, [0.06750856214219292], [0], [1356998400000000000])
[1] (1, [0.8728395428343044], [1], [1356998460000000000])
[2] (2, [0.37963409103250334], [2], [1356998520000000000])
[3] (3, [0.5528271410494643], [3], [1356998580000000000])
[4] (4, [0.9961498806897623], [4], [1356998640000000000])
```

`datetime64[ns]` are serialized to nanoseconds since epoch in UTC and stored as an `int64` column type (this is the same as numpy stores the underlying data). So its pretty straightforward to read this in as it is standard HDF5 format. You would need, however, to interpret the meta data. See the source file in `pandas/io/pytables.py`.

Basically you would look for `datetime64` kind blocks (the kind maps the names of those coulmns). Then you can reverse convert in IDL/matlab (in pandas you would do `pd.to_datetime(ns_since_epoch,unit='ns')`. Timezones are a bit more tricky as the values are UTC, and the timezone is stored in the `info` attribute.

Note: this is slightly different in the interpretation of the meta-data for a `Fixed` format or if you have `data_columns` (but not very difficult to do).