# converting date to datenum using pandas giving invalid token errors

Tags: python, pandas, matlab

I am trying to change python datetime into  matlab datenum by using
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776414/python-datetime-to-matlab-datenum/9391765#9391765) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776414/python-datetime-to-matlab-datenum/9260102#9260102)

```html
 def datetime2matlabdn(dt):
   ord = dt.toordinal()
   mdn = dt + timedelta(days = 366)
   frac = (dt-datetime(dt.year,dt.month,dt.day,0,0,0)).seconds / (24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0)
   return mdn.toordinal() + frac
```

when I call datetime2matlabdn(2021-08-28 10:30:00)  it throws  FOLLOWING ERRORS

```
datetime2matlabdn(2021-08-28 10:30:00)
Syntax Error: invalid token
```

what is wrong with my syntax? if I try to remove these zeros then it throws invalid syntax error.
I figured out I need to strip the zeros
I tried some thing like this but it is not working

```
dt=dt.strptime('2021-06-28 10:30','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    dn=datetime2matlabdn(dt)
```

how can I strip my zeros in function.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see [the help on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting); don't use a Stack Snippet for code that doesn't run in one, such as MATLAB or Python. Simply indent by four spaces or use triple backticks to make the syntax highlighting show up.

Comment: I don9t know why they close the question when I mentioned that I am getting error in running the code. it throws invalid token error